# Set the default image zoom for full screen in magento 2.x

Tags: magento2, zoom, fotorama

I have found the magnify settings in view.xml which allow me to turn off and on the full screen mode. I have also used the fullscreenzoom integer to reduce the steps to zooming in fully, however....

Our product images when zoomed in are 2000px tall. When somebody clicks the full screen button we want it to load up with the full size of the image zoomed in 100% with no option to zoom in and out, just the option to move around the image. I cannot seem to find a setting for selecting the default level of zoom.

It is annoying for the image to come up small then have to click the + symbol a few times, then when swiping to the next image having to zoom again.

Does anyone know a way for the full screen zoom to just be 100% with no + / - symbols.

Thanks,
Glynn

Answer (score 1):

In your theme's `/etc/view.xml` file try the following settings:

```
<var name="magnifier">
   <var name="enabled">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
</var>
```

and/or

```
<var name="allowfullscreen">true</var>
```

Answer (score 0):

copy

```
 vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/etc/view.xml
```

To custom theme

```
app/design/frontend/{theme}/{themename}/etc/view.xml
```

search magnifier tag/var in view.xml file.

In magnifier tag change enabled variable value

```
 <var name="enabled">true</var>
```

remove cache and refresh page.

Answer (score 0):

Magento default not provide magifier in fotoroma full screen slider, but if requirement then you need to add custom magnifier on fotoroma full screen slider.