# Magento2 - How to add magnifier zoom effect on fotorama fullscreen?

Tags: magento2, fotorama-slider

I need to add magnifier zoom effect in fotoroma fullscreen.

Attached the screen shot here. 
[image]

Comment: i think helpful this link :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/265742/set-the-default-image-zoom-for-full-screen-in-magento-2-x

Comment: Hello mohit, I have tried but i want magnifier on fotoroma full screen slider, not pdp page fotoroma slider